# How to use JSON data in your Ajax success

Tags: arrays, json, ajax

I send some data using the AJAX request.

On my PHP page I have following code.

```
$rouid = "";
if (isset($_POST['routeid'])) {
    $rouid = $_POST['routeid'];

    $array = array('routeid' => $rouid);
    echo json_encode($array);
}
```

I am encoding the data into JSON.

Now I want to send this json back to my original page where I sent data from.

How can I get this `$array` variable into ajax request success.

Answer (score 0):

```
var routeid=$('#routeid').val();

$.ajax({
   url:"yoururlhere",
   type:"post",
   data:{routeid: routeid},
   dataType:"json",
   contentType:"application/json",
   success:function(response){
       console.log(response);
       var ROUTEID=response.routeid;
   },error:function(err){
      alert("ERROR")
   }
});
```